# Google Drive Ruby - accessing files via a service account

Tags: ruby, google-api, google-drive-api

I've been using the [Google Drive Ruby](https://github.com/gimite/google-drive-ruby) gem to access information from Google spreadsheets, and, with the impending deprecation of a lot of stuff, have been forced to upgrade, and can now no longer log on with a simple username and password (I understand this is being deprecated too)

After flipping various options and making certain incantations, I've managed to get logged in via Oauth like so:

```
client = Google::APIClient.new(application_name: 'Google Drive Ruby test', application_version: '0.0.1')
key = Google::APIClient::KeyUtils.load_from_pkcs12(
  'config/key.p12',
  ENV['GAPPS_KEY_PASSWORD']
)

asserter = Google::APIClient::JWTAsserter.new(
  ENV['GAPPS_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL'],
  ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'],
  key
)

client.authorization = asserter.authorize
auth_token = client.authorization.access_token

google_drive = GoogleDrive.login_with_oauth(access_token)
```

This works fine, however, I only seem to be able to act as my service account, so don't have access to the files that other users have access to. For example:

```
google_drive.spreadsheet_by_key("18rNqAz3R0hhp7OYEPLU8thGHsUR0jgYgHk3zQ8CWL-4")
```

Returns:

```
Google::APIClient::ClientError: File not found: 18rNqAz3R0hhp7OYEPLU8thGHsUR0jgYgHk3zQ8CWL-4
```

I understand that you can act as a given user, but despite trawling through the docs, I don't seem to be able to get this to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Service accounts are not for this (which is 2legged oauth2). You want a client flow (3 legged oauth2) where you end up storing each users refresh tokens and use them to access data in THEIR drive. Sorry im not familiar with the ruby side.

Answer (score 1):

You have to share your spreadsheet with this client mail id - `ENV['GAPPS_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL']`

Otherwise you won't be able to access anything even though you have a valid token.